# Change Feed Data Persist

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, fiware-cosmos

I wanted to know how long the Azure Cosmos DB change feed persist the changed data if I set the TTL(Time to Live) property for the document to -1

Answer (score 1):

ChangeFeed will also persist forever.